# how can I check if a string is a positive integer?

Tags: c#, parsing, int

I mean :

```
1231 YES
121.1241 NO
121,1241 NO
-121 NO
124a NO
```

how can i do it faster in C#?

Comment: Positive integer in what range? (What should it do for values greater than `int.MaxValue` or `int.LongValue`?) Are leading spaces valid? What about a leading + sign?

Comment: Oh, and what about 0? Did you really mean *positive*, or non-negative?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
int x;
if (int.TryParse(str, out x) && x > 0)
```

Comment: why not `uint.TryParse(str, out x)` instead? i could imagine that it is also more efficient since it doesnt have to check for `-`

Comment: I think it needs a little more explanation (instead of writing the code).

Answer (score 9):

You can check if it only contains digits:

```
if (theString.All(Char.IsDigit))
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to actually *parsing* it is to check if the string is non-empty and *only* contains digits, optionally with a leading `+` sign if you want to allow that.

Note that this won't perform any range checking - so 9999999999999999999999999999999999 would be valid, even though it wouldn't fit into an `int` or a `long`.

You could use a regex for that, or possibly LINQ:

```
var nonNegative = text.Length > 0 && text.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9');
```

(This is similar to Guffa's `Char.IsDigit` approach, but restricts itself to ASCII digits. There are numerous non-ASCII digits in Unicode.)

Note that this will restrict it to *non-negative* values - not just *positive* values. How would you want to treat "0" and "0000"?